# First Order Differential Equation Problem Substitution or bernoulli

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the equation

$$dy/dx + xy = y^4$$

using Bernoulli's method but it seems to fail since I end up with

$$dv/dx -1/3(xv) = -1/3(v)^-8 $$

I am not sure what to do... Any help would mean a lot.

I understand that that standard form of a Bernoulli equation is:

$$ dy/dx + p(x)y = q(x)y^n$$

Can I assume q(x) = 0 and apply bernoulli's equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let $u(x)=1/y(x)^3$, then
$$
u'(x)=-\frac{3}{y(x)^4}y'(x).
$$
Your equation becomes
$$
u'(x)=-\frac{3}{y(x)^4}\bigl(y(x)^4-xy(x)\bigr)=-3+3xu(x).
$$
The solution is not an elementary function, though.

Answer (score 0):

This example has the form of a Bernoulli ODE

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x)y^n$$ where $\; n = 4, \; p(x)= x \;$ and $\; q(x) = 1$

We make the substitution
$\ v = y^{1-n} = y^{-3}$ and we need to find the values of  $\frac{dy}{dx},\; y\;$ and $\;y^n.$

Here they are:

$y = v^{-1/3}$

$y^4  = v^{-4/3}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{3}v^{-4/3}\frac{dv}{dx}\quad$

Substituting them in the original equation we find
$$-\frac{1}{3}v^{-4/3}\frac{dv}{dx} + xv^{-1/3} = v^{-4/3}$$

Dividing this equation by $-\frac{1}{3}v^{-4/3}$ we get the standard form of the first-order linear ODE
$$\frac{dv}{dx} - 3xv = -3$$